# Android app works on emulator but not on phone

Tags: android, android-emulator

So I've made this game for android-phones, that runs perfectly fine on my emulator. The problem is that when i try to run it on my phone, it just turns back to the in-app menu when i try to launch the game - I don't get any error messages. 
Any tips on why this happens, and how I can possibly fix it.

btw. The phone I am using is HTC Desire

Update:
I tried testing it on an SIII. Here I got a crash message instead.
The android emulator, and the HTC Desire runs Android 2.2 while the SIII runs Android 4.0

Comment: Do you have any log files? Which Android version? In which conditions did you test it?

Comment: do you have all of the correct permissions enabled in the manifest?

Comment: Try testing in another device.

Comment: Assuming you don't know, the usual approach would be to connect the phone to a PC using USB Debugging, then use *adb logcat* to get the error log (either directly or using Eclipse). It is customary to then include this log with your question, so we actually have some information to go on.